# using of extern "C" without function

Tags: c++, c, com

I read the Dale Rogerson's book "Inside COM". In a chapter 5, he wrote (sorry, I translated in English):

> *extern "C"* is for C linkage. If **a function** is marked as *extern "C"*,
>   compiler wil not change function's name to other, for example:
>   `?CreateInstance@@YAPAUIUncnown@@XZ`.

It is clear for me. But further the author uses `extern "C"` in other place and doesn't explain the reason of it:

```
#include <objbase.h>

extern "C" 
{
    // {32bb8320-b41b-11cf-a6bb-0080c7b2d682}
    extern const IID IID_IX = 
        {0x32bb8320, 0xb41b, 0x11cf,
        {0xa6, 0xbb, 0x0, 0x80, 0xc7, 0xb2, 0xd6, 0x82}} ;

    // {32bb8321-b41b-11cf-a6bb-0080c7b2d682}
    extern const IID IID_IY = 
        {0x32bb8321, 0xb41b, 0x11cf,
        {0xa6, 0xbb, 0x0, 0x80, 0xc7, 0xb2, 0xd6, 0x82}} ;

    // {32bb8322-b41b-11cf-a6bb-0080c7b2d682}
    extern const IID IID_IZ = 
        {0x32bb8322, 0xb41b, 0x11cf,
        {0xa6, 0xbb, 0x0, 0x80, 0xc7, 0xb2, 0xd6, 0x82}} ;

    // The extern is required to allocate memory for C++ constants.
}
```

It is not a function... Why author used `extern "C"` in this case?

Best Regards,
Andrey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

extern "C" on a block like that is like applying extern "C" to every declaration in the block; it declares all of them to use C linkage.

extern "C" on a non-function does the same thing as extern "C" on a function; it makes the object use C semantics for naming, and whatever else is relevant.

For details you might want to refer to the standard, clause 7.5 Linkage specifications [dcl.link] (though it's written using a difficult form of English).

---

Language linkage is to make it possible to access the declared entities from a different language. What exactly this means is up to a particular language and C++ implementation. Traditionally with C it means that the symbols and calling conventions for functions are changed. As far as I can recall, in most implementations nothing is different for non-functions. It's just that the language specification doesn't say you can expect accessing those entities from C to work unless you use extern "C".

Comment: What will change, if I remove 'extern "C" ' from its block?

Comment: @Bush - maybe nothing. Depends on the compiler. In general, things that you want to be able to use from both C++ and C should be marked `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 0):

probably just a silly workaround for your issue. what i found is that, while using c functions in cpp file, theoretically extern is required. But i found that in eclipse oxygen version, we do not have to specify extern c, we can directly use c functions and printf statements too in cpp file and it just works fine. Havent tried in older versions of eclipse.

My solution may not be very helpful, but you could give it a try. It worked for me.

As far as I remember the standard, all function declarations are considered as "extern" by default, so there is no need to specify it explicitly. That doesn't make this keyword useless since it can also be used with variables (and it that case - it's the only solution to solve linkage problems). But with the functions - yes, it's optional.

A little more verbose answer is that it allows you to use variables compiled in another source code file, but doesn't reserve memory for the variable. So, to utilise extern, you have to have a source code file or a library unit that contains memory space for the variable on the top level (not within functions). Now, you can refer to that variable by defining an extern variable of the same name in your other source code files.

In general, the use of extern definition should be avoided. They lead easily to unmanagable code and errors that hard to locate. Of course, there are examples where other solutions would be impractical, but they are rare. For example, stdin and stdout are macros that are mapped to an extern array variable of type FILE* in stdin.h; memory space for this array is in a standard C-library unit.